# web api not finding the Get method - 500 error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

When i try to make a call to the web api to get a single vendor. It is return a 500 error.

I try to break inside the Get(Guid id) but it never gets inside of it.

I know it is getting to the controller but looks like it can't find the Get(Guid id) function.

Any ideas why? Am I missing something?

web api route

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Module",
                routeTemplate: "api/module/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
                defaults: new {  id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

api controller

```
namespace App.WebUI.Controllers.api.Module
{
    public class VendorsController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly UnitOfWork _repository = new UnitOfWork();


        // GET api/Module/vendors
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
           return all; 

        }

        // GET api/Module/vendors/5
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(Guid id)
        {
           return single
        }

        // POST api/Module/vendors
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(Vendor vendor)
        {
           insert single
        }

        [HttpPut]
        //PUT api/Module/Vendors
        public HttpResponseMessage Put(Vendor vendor)
        {
            update single
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's internal error, not 404. Do you have any global action filters registered or delegating handlers?

Comment: Is there an error message? What is the URL that you're calling?

Comment: What URL is your test URL?

Comment: your `routeTemplate` does not match your commented URLs.  Try `api/module/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

Comment: url = localhost/api/module/vendors/{guid}

Comment: I am getting 500 error; Response message = {"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred."} which doesn't help at all

Comment: No I do not have any filters registered or delegating handlers

Comment: Jonesy: That doesn't match the route config, but i try anyway and didn't work.

Comment: What's the method body for your methods?  I presume that you've removed it for conciseness in your code above.  A 500 error could indicate that the issue is within the method.  How are you so sure that it's unable to resolve to an action?  On a slightly related note, I think that your routing template is questionable as well.

Comment: Inside the function I have a try and catch. No exception is thrown and I place a break point on the first statement inside the try and the application never hits the break point. About the routing template, what do you think is wrong with it. It works fine for the other controllers. @JoshuaShearer

Comment: I suppose what's most confusing regarding your routing is that I can't understand the reasoning for why you would want to swap the `action` and `id` parameters.  In your routing you can't rely on the `action` parameter to identify a valid endpoint because you can't concretely identify which parameter is for `action` and which one is for `id`, because there are no constraints on either.  This seems like a great opportunity to use [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: I swap the action and id to handle rest web api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i had to do to make it work.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Module",
                routeTemplate: "api/module/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
                defaults: new {  id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "DefaultAction" }
            );
```

Then at the default Action(GET(), GET(id), POST(), PUT(), DELETE()) I added the data annotation: [ActionName("DefaultAction")]